# i am finding difficult to understand the issue i am facing with the foreach loop

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is check file extension of the file, if the extension of the file matches with the any of the element of the extensions array then i am calling the function get_size() else I am displaying the error file not matched...
The problem is whether the extension matches or not the else statement of my code gets executed however i only want to execute else statement if the extension doesn’t match Below is my code

```
// getting the extension of the file 
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// allowed extension array
$extensions= array('txt','xls','xlsm','xlsx','xlsm','csv' );
// foreach loop for checking if extensions matches or not
foreach ($extensions as $extres) 
{
    # code...
    if($extres===$ext)
    {
        get_size();
    }

    else 
    {
        # code...
        $once=1;

    }

}
if($once==1)
{
    exit("Sorry file not matched");
}
```

Comment: `$once` will be `1` unless the extension matches *every* element in the array, which, of course, isn't possible.

Comment: Please change the logic, 1. Initialize the $once to 1 before the foreachloop. 2. Set the $once to 0 if there is a match in ($extres===$ext). 3. Things will work fine. Reason: Extension will match only once among all the extension, so the rest all will set the $once to 1 and thus goes into else case.

Comment: @jeffrycopps i have already initialized $once=0 before foreach loop

Comment: After `get_size();` stop looping the `foreach` with `break;`

Comment: Take a look at the function [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
// getting the extension of the file 
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSIO-N);
// allowed extension array
$extensions= array('txt','xls','xlsm','xlsx','xlsm','csv' );
// foreach loop for checking if extensions matches or not
$once = 1;
foreach ($extensions as $extres) 
{
    # code...
    if($extres===$ext)
    {
        get_size();
        $once = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        # code...
        //$once=1; //Remove the else part.
    }
}
if($once==1)
{
    exit("Sorry file not matched");
}
```